# Is there a plugin for rating of multiple questions for wordpress?

Tags: rating

I have developed a site in worpdress. I need to manage a different questions like "How would you rate our customer service", "How satisfied were you with our service" and more questions and rate these questions and have view on the admin. I tried to find the plugin but could not find. Can anyone let me know if that type of plugin exists or do I need to do with my own codes?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a plugin - GD Star Ratings.  I am using it here: http://apluginforthat.com/gd-star-ratings/.  You can customize your questions, type of ratings (thumbs up/down vs stars) and much more.  You can also configure it to have the ratings appear in your dashboard.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think it will work for me. But there so many settings to be done. Can you please give me documentation link to see how the setting works and rest setting? Thank you again for your great help...

Comment: You just need to navigate the directions on the plugin site.  It took me a while to figure it out.